# Compatibility of Spring Boot 1.5.x with Hibernate 4.x

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, version, upgrade

We have upgraded Spring Boot from 1.2.4 to 1.5.8, which automatically upgraded Hibernate from 4.3.10 to 5.0.12. We are facing some Hibernate issues and we would like to use this version of Spring Boot but downgrade Hibernate back to 4.3.10.

Is spring Boot 1.5.8 compatible with Hibernate 4.3.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is according to the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data).

Just make sure you override the (inherited from spring-boot-depencies) version of hibernate in your pom:

```
<properties>        
    <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

> Hibernate 4.3 will not be supported past Spring Boot 1.4. Please raise an issue if you find a bug that prevents you from upgrading.